# append new elements to JSON array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following JSON array

```
 var feeds =   {"data":[{"id":"128811893769_10152115787143770"},{"id":"128811893769_10152115787143770"}]}
```

How to add new key and values in to json i.e(likes_count,share_count)

```
$.each(feeds.data, function (i, item) {
    $.getJSON("facebook_feeds.php?result_type=getCounts&id="+item.id, 
        function(summary) {                         
            var likesCount = summary[0].like_info.like_count;                      
            var shareCount = summary[0].share_info.share_count;             
        });
});
```

I want to push the key and values in to feeds array

Comment: where do you want to push key value?  inside feeds['data'] or directly to feeds?

Comment: need to push into  feeds.data

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  feeds.data.push({"likesCount": likesCount});
  feeds.data.push({"shareCount": shareCount});
```

Comment: some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

The **push()** alternative is the contact alternative which gives the opportunity to use both **jQuery** and **javascript** as well

```js
/*
 * Extend Array extra json
 * Example: 
 * $.extendArray([{a:1,b:2}],[{c:3,d:4}]) return -> [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}]
 * $.extendArray([{a:1,b:2}],{c:3,d:4}) return -> [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}]
 *
 */
$.extend({
  extendArray: function() {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
  }
});
// Array inside json 
var arr = $.extendArray([{a:1,b:2}],[{c:3,d:4},{e:4,f:5},{g:6,h:7}]);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two approaches for it.
1.  directly add likesCount and shareCount in `item`  [ Item is holding current feed.data element ]
OR
2.  Use `extend` method of jQuery, ( I wont suggest using it for such trivial thing )

```
$.each(feeds.data, function (i, item) {
    $.getJSON("facebook_feeds.php?result_type=getCounts&id="+item.id, 
        function(summary) {                         
            var likesCount = summary[0].like_info.like_count;                      
            var shareCount = summary[0].share_info.share_count;  

            // Approach 1
            item['likesCount'] =  likesCount;   
            item['shareCount'] =  shareCount;   
            // Approach 2
            $.extend ( item, { 'likesCount' : likesCount ,  'shareCount' : shareCount } );         
        });
});
```